# Automated deployment pipeline from GitHub to Salesforce.com

Tags: github, salesforce

I have apex code stored in the master branch of my remote repository in GitHub and would like to deploy it directly into my Salesforce Org.

Is there a way to setup a "pipeline" in GitHub with Salesforce.com in order to facilitate a direct deployment into Salesforce?

Edited on 22nd-Oct-2022: is there a way to setup a button on GitHub that I can click on when I want to deploy changes (delta) from the master branch to a related Salesforce DEV Org?

Answer (score 0):

Learn from Salesforce themselves. The https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes (all lwc demos mentioned in documentation) contains actions to run code quality tools (prettier, lint), unit tests (apex, jest), deploy to scratch org, assign permission set, run all tests, delete the scratch org, report on code coverage...

Lots of goodies there. Might be too much if you're just after plain deploy to prod but it's good to know what toys are out there.